# Why does /dev/random on ubuntu generate data slower than on debian?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, random, debian, entropy

During test of a copy function I've copied data from /dev/random to /dev/null and measured the throughput. On my Debian testing machine, I'm getting about 200 kb/s consistently. On Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu testing and a server running Linux 3.12.53-40 (no name) I'm getting 2 bytes/s.

Wiki says that /dev/random only has a limited entropy pool and blocks when that is empty. However I can't find anything on why Debian generates that much faster?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be better to ask this question on [su]

Comment: you are testing against 2 machines so i would be very surprised if this stat actually makes sense. your ubuntu could lack of entropy while you were testing.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I've got a my home machine (Debian), a friends two machines (Ubuntu LTS and Testing) and a university server (self-compiled linux probably). My home machine, the only one that's running Debian get's the 200kb/s, all the others are getting 2bytes/s. I know that this these numbers don't make sense, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Thank's, I'll try there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the exact reason is with those distribution version that you mention, but it is my understanding that `/dev/random` operates by gathering random data from spurious events such as the irregularly timing between input events from keyboard/mice, noise from idle audio inputs etc.

It is known that when the amount of random data is insufficient, `/dev/random` will simply block until it gathers more. So difference in speed between distributions boils down to how many and how fast the sources of random data are.

This could be as simple as having different audio driver, different audio settings and any number of other user configurable things.

In the end, the tip is to use `/dev/urandom` (notice the extra *U*) as this will instead of block simply "spin" the data it has already in a cryptographically sound PRNG.

I hope this answer albeit it's lack of concrete facts at least explains what is going on. Here is a [link](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) with some more discussion of the topic of `/dev/random` vs. `/dev/urandom`

Comment: Also as an experiment: try recording a lot of audio or moving your mouse around. Yes, that actually makes a difference! I have experienced this first hand.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. However that still doesn't explain why /dev/random behaves differently on distros that I expect to behave similarly. I'm curious where I'm wrong.